Incorrect limit involving hyperbolic Kepler equations
I’m trying to work with the Kepler equations for a hyperbolic trajectory in the case of a repulsive force (see Wikipedia for the attractive case). The trajectory can be described by the right branch of the hyperbola of equation $\frac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.
e = -Sqrt[(b/a)^2 + 1] (* eccentricity *)
c = Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] (* linear eccentricity, half the distance between each focci *)
y = b*Sqrt[(x - c)^2/a^2 - 1]
\[Phi] = ArcTan[y/x] (* angle from the left focus at (0,0) *)
H = 2*ArcTanh[Sqrt[(e - 1)/(e + 1)]*Tan[\[Phi]/2]] (* Hyperbolic anomaly, also denoted E *)
M = e*Sinh[H] - H

$M$ is the mean anomaly, and it is proportional to time. Therefore, we expect $lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$ to approach something inversely proportional to the horizontal speed when the particle is at infinity $v_{x \infty}$ (or more exactly $\frac{-c}{a^2}$).
However, Mathematica evaluates this symbolic limit as 0:
With[{f = D[M, x]}, 
 Limit[f, x -> +\[Infinity], 
  Assumptions -> 
   a > 0 && b > 0 && Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals]]]

(* 0 *)

Which is clearly physically wrong. Graphing the derivative for some arbitrary $a$ and $b$ also shows the limit seems to be non-zero.
With[{f = D[M, x]}, 
 Block[{a = 3, b = 2}, Plot[{f, -c/a^2}, {x, 0, 10^4}]]]


Why does Mathematica return this incorrect result and how to avoid unknowingly encountering it?

I suspect a coefficient in the series expansion is mistaken for zero but I'm not absolutely certain about this.

If you Simplify the expression for H before taking the Limit, Mathematica gets it right.
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

e = -Sqrt[(b/a)^2 + 1] (*eccentricity*);
c = Sqrt[a^2 + 
    b^2] (*linear eccentricity,half the distance between each focci*);
y = b*Sqrt[(x - c)^2/a^2 - 1];
\[Phi] = ArcTan[y/x] (*angle from the left focus at (0,0)*);

H = Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0,
   2*ArcTanh[Sqrt[(e - 1)/(e + 1)]*Tan[\[Phi]/2]] //
    FullSimplify] (*Hyperbolic anomaly,also denoted E*);

M = e*Sinh[H] - H;

lim = Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0,
  With[{f = D[M, x]}, Limit[f, x -> +\[Infinity]] // FullSimplify]]

(* -(((a^2 + b^2) (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + Sqrt[
       b^2 + 2 a (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])]) Cos[
      1/2 ArcTan[b/a]]^2)/(a^2 (b^2 + 2 a (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])))) *)

lim = Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0,
  lim // TrigReduce // FullSimplify]

(* -((Sqrt[a^2 + 
   b^2] (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]) (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + Sqrt[
    b^2 + 2 a (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])]))/(
 2 a^2 (b^2 + 2 a (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])))) *)

This is equal to -c/a^2
Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, lim == -c/a^2 // Simplify]

(* True *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{D[M, x], lim} /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}], {x, 0, 10^4}],
 {{a0, 3, "a"}, 0.1, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b0, 2, "b"}, 0.1, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a0, b0}]



I advise you to cut the problem into small steps when you deal with a complicated expression like this.
How about FullSimplify[]ing the function before taking the limit?:
f = FullSimplify[D[M,x],Assumptions-> a>0 && b>0]


ans = Assuming[a>0 && b>0, Limit[f, x -> +\[Infinity]]]


We get a conditional expression, but as we will see, the condition is satisfied under your assumption:
ans[[2]]


FullSimplify[ans[[2]],Assumptions->(a>0&&b>0)]
(* True *)

So the wanted result is given by
ans[[1]]


This can be simplified further:
Simplify[TrigReduce[TrigExpand[ans[[1]]]]]



Your last expression can be simplified as  -Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]/a^2

Thanks, I’d upvote if I could. I’m unsure about marking this as accepted because I realized I did not specify my question, which is more about why Mathematica returns this incorrect result and how to avoid it. I’ll edit the question accordingly, but maybe this is better suited by asking a new question.

@RedBorg I don't know, either, why Mathematica returns incorrect result. If I had a lot of time I could pin down where was the fork. Simplification process is always problematic especially for multi-valued function (as a function of complex domain) like this.
